# Can a value be retrieved from Generated Source, using Selenium IDE

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, strategy

The Scenario: I enter transaction data and submit that data to the application. The application responds with a transaction ID. I then take the Submission Transaction ID and use that ID to query the application. The goal is that the submitted data and the received data are the same.

The issue - The transaction ID is located only on the generated source page.

Using Selenium IDE is there a way that I can retrieve that transaction ID from the generated source page?

Comment: Please give more details on _ _I then take the Submission Transaction ID and use that ID to query the application__ = How exactly do you do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `storeText` command to save the text of an element into the specified variable, and then use the `assertText` command to assert that another element has that text. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091218/how-can-i-store-a-dynamic-text-value-in-selenium-ide-and-use-it-later-in-differe